# How to overcome from the error " The requested URL was not found on this server "in AVfoundation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I am working on video app.I have to capture and trim the video.I had done this using AVFoundation framework.When I am calling trim method I am getting error " The requested URL was not found on this server".

I used the following code to trim and play the video

```
- (IBAction)showTrimmedVideo:(UIButton *)sender
{

[self deleteTmpFile];

   NSURL *videoFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:originalVideoPath];
NSLog(@"Video to trim is %@",videoFileUrl);

AVAsset *anAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoFileUrl options:nil];
NSArray *compatiblePresets = [AVAssetExportSession exportPresetsCompatibleWithAsset:anAsset];
if ([compatiblePresets containsObject:AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality])
{

    self.exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                          initWithAsset:anAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
    // Implementation continues.

           NSURL *furl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:originalVideoPath];
    NSLog(@"Original file path is %@",furl);

    self.exportSession.outputURL = furl;
    self.exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;

    CMTime start = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(self.startTime, anAsset.duration.timescale);
    CMTime duration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(self.stopTime-self.startTime, anAsset.duration.timescale);
    CMTimeRange range = CMTimeRangeMake(start, duration);
    self.exportSession.timeRange = range;

    self.trimBtn.hidden = YES;
    self.myActivityIndicator.hidden = NO;
    [self.myActivityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

        switch ([self.exportSession status])
        {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"Export failed: %@", [[self.exportSession error] localizedDescription]);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"Export canceled");
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"NONE");
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.myActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
                    self.myActivityIndicator.hidden = YES;
                    self.trimBtn.hidden = NO;
                    [self playMovie:self.tmpVideoPath];
                });

                break;
        }
    }];

}
```

}

```
 -(void)deleteTmpFile
{

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:originalVideoPath];
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
BOOL exist = [fm fileExistsAtPath:url.path];
NSError *err;
if (exist) {
    [fm removeItemAtURL:url error:&err];
    NSLog(@"file deleted");
    if (err)
    {
        NSLog(@"file remove error, %@", err.localizedDescription );
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"no file by that name");
}
```

}

Every time its going into " AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:" case and showing above error.
I am not getting where I had gone wrong.Please suggest me what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

you problem here is, you are first deleting the file and trying to use it with export session. You should not delete the file while export is in progress, and I recommend you to save exported file to temporary directory, after export is done, just delete your old file and move the exported one to the original file URL. Good Luck!

Comment: And ya, when using file system with URLs, I think libraries use the file system as server, that's why it's saying that it couldn't find the file on the server.